# PDF first page thumbnail

Tags: react-native, pdf, png

I have created React Native App using Expo. I use Document Picker to get pdf files from user. But I want to show them as images(Render first page img to be sure that everything is ok).
Is there any possible solutions for react-native with expo?

I tried pdf-lib but dont find how to render first page as png